# eslint-webpack-plugin does not emit warnings or errors

Tags: webpack, eslint, typescript-eslint

Errors specifically added in the code for testing purposes, but no warnings or errors are emitted in the output.
The commented lines in the plugin are the attempts I made.

I also tried with the deprecated **eslint-loader** and it seems to work, I didn't analized the output.
Calling eslint from command line works

Other tries:

- Changed the plugin order
- Removed other plugins
- npm clean-install
- upgraded all packages
- imported .eslintrc directly in plugin options with options.baseConfig
- used the webpack-format extensions array: ['.ts', '.tsx']

```js
module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'production',
    node: {
        __dirname: false,
        __filename: false,
    },
    entry: [path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'src', 'server', 'server.tsx')],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'build'),
        filename: 'server.js',
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: false,
    },
    externalsPresets: {
        node: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new ESLintPlugin({
            // files: 'src/**/*',
            // context: 'src',
            extensions: ['ts', 'tsx'],
            emitError: true,
            emitWarning: true,
        }),
        //...
    ],
    module: { 
        rules: [
            //...
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        comments: true,
                        sourceMaps: false,
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react', '@babel/typescript'],
                        plugins: [
                            [
                                '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                                {
                                    loose: true,
                                },
                            ],
                            '@babel/transform-runtime',
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
            //...
        ]
     },
};
```

my .eslintrc

```json
    {
        "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
        "extends": [
            "plugin:react/recommended",
            "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
            "plugin:prettier/recommended",
            "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
            "prettier/react"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaFeatures": {
                "jsx": true
            },
            "ecmaVersion": 2020,
            "sourceType": "module",
            "tsconfigRootDir": "/"
        },
        "rules": {
            "react/prop-types": 0,
            "prettier/prettier": 1,
            "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
            "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 0,
            "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": 0
        },
        "settings": {
            "react": {
                "version": "detect"
            }
        },
        "env": {
            "browser": true,
            "node": true,
            "es2020": true
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-webpack-plugin/issues/59